# How do I initialize conda as default in WSL2?

Tags: ubuntu, conda, wsl-2

Many researchers are aware that **WSL2** enables the use of Linux within Windows. As I also needed to work in a Linux environment, I installed it. Afterward, I needed Anaconda3 (conda), so I downloaded the .sh installer for Anaconda3 and installed it. However, when I attempted to set **conda as the default, **it disappeared after shutting down and restarting**.

```
$ conda
conda: command not found
```

So I always need to do:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

but I want to set **default**. Other post says do this code:

```
$ cd anaconda3/bin/
$ ./conda init
```

But the message shows this:

```
no change     /home/wyt/anaconda3/condabin/conda
no change     /home/wyt/anaconda3/bin/conda
no change     /home/wyt/anaconda3/bin/conda-env
no change     /home/wyt/anaconda3/bin/activate
no change     /home/wyt/anaconda3/bin/deactivate
no change     /home/wyt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /home/wyt/anaconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /home/wyt/anaconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /home/wyt/anaconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /home/wyt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     /home/wyt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
no change     /home/wyt/.bashrc
No action taken.
```

How can I solve this problem?